# How to reach subdata in MongoDb?

Tags: java, mongodb

Hello I can easily reach data in MongoDb like this;

Jar Files,

> bson-3.4.2.jar,
>   mongodb-driver-3.4.2.jar,
>   mongodb-driver-async-3.4.2.jar,
>   mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2.jar

JAVA

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("192.168.56.101",27017);
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("dbTest2");
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("colTest2");
str=Objects.toString(collection.count());
Document myDoc = collection.find().first();
id=Objects.toString(myDoc.get("_id"));
```

HTLM

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
<h:head>
    <title>MongoDB Test</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h1>Number of data : #{obj.str}</h1>
    <h1>ID : #{obj.id}</h1>
</h:body>
```

But the question is how do I reach subdata in this? All I can get is markers and it gives both of them, I just need firstmarker to print out;

```
{ 
   "_id" : "test",
   "status" : 2,
   "time" : null,
   "markers" :{
         "firstmarker" : 1,
         "secondmarker" : 2,
   },
   "batchid" : 15000234
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple, since it's JSON format which is key-value pair, all you need is to access value by providing key.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
<h:head>
  <title>MongoDB Test</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
   <h1>Number of data : #{obj.str}</h1>
   <h1>ID : #{obj.id}</h1>
   <h1>FirstMarker : #{obj.markers.firstmarker}</h1>
</h:body>
```

Edit: To access value in java use below code< I'm using version 3.4.2 of mongo java drivers.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
final MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
final DB database = mongoClient.getDB("dbTest2");
final DBCollection collection = database.getCollection("colTest2");
final long count = collection.count();
final DBObject dbObject = new BasicDBObject();
dbObject.put("_id", "test");
final DBCursor curr = collection.find(dbObject);
while (curr.hasNext()) {
    final DBObject dbo = curr.next();
    final BSONObject object = (BSONObject) dbo.get("markers");
    System.out.println(object.get("firstmarker"));
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there a way I can take inside object as an object in Java folder?

Comment: what do you mean by "Java folder"?

Comment: I meant in Java part, sorry. Let's say I need to change the subdata in Java but I can only reach first object.

Comment: Ok, you can easily access the way you are accessing _id attribute Objects.toString(myDoc.get("markers").get("firstmarker"));

Comment: I saw the same example in here somewhere but the problem is I don't have the second 'get' all I got is getClass, which have no use for me. Is there a problem with jar files or something changed in new versions?

Comment: Sorry I thought it had a method to return a document but it does not have one, please see my updated answer